# About pom.xml run and outputs

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am new to pom and i run the below pom.xml it executed successfully but there is no results found in under target folder.

please tell me how to execute my pom and where i found my results (Like : Outputs)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">   

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>xx_groupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>yy_artifactid</artifactId>   
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>yy_artifactid</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
      </plugin> 

      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.15</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.15</version>
      </plugin>  

    </plugins>
  </build> 
</project>
```

Comment: What did you run? `mvn package`? What did Maven say (usually there is *extensive* console output)

Answer (score 0):

the pom is valid, try:

```
mvn package
```

if everything goes well, maven will package your project into a jar file at target/yy_artifactid-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

--edit--

you can use [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to run java programs

add the the plugin to your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
        <argument>-classpath</argument>
        <classpath/>
        <argument>org.example.Main</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

remember to change the org.example.Main to the main class of your program which should contains a static entry method: ** public static void main (String[] args)**

and then run: **mvn compile exec:exec**

to execute the unit tests of your application, put test cases under src/test/java fold, and run **mvn test**

Comment: Thanks for replay and i got the jar file, please tell me how to execute this jar file for get my results.

Comment: I am not using the **public static void main (String[] args)** my file having the junit code  EX: import org.junit.Test;
 
public class OrderTest1 {
 
    @Test
    public void login_Flowelltest() {
     System.out.println("test1");
    }   }